# Find dimension of kernel.

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $T:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is an onto linear transformation with $m>n$, what is $\dim(\ker(T))$? Explain.

I'm trying to understand this. A detailed explanation would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Using the very famous [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) :

$$\dim(\mathbb R^m)=\dim(\ker T)+\dim(\text{Im}(T)).$$

Comment: It should read $\dim(\mathbb R^m)=\dim(\ker T)+\dim(\text{Im}(T)).$

Comment: @Fred: thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Think this way:

If T is onto, can you say how many elements have a basis of $Im(T)$?

But isn't $Im(T)$ a subspace of $R^n$? If so, can you find a basis to $R^n$ containing a basis of $Im(T)$?

Can you finish from here?